# which type of data source we are using for high performance?

Tags: database, database-connection, datasource, sqldatasource

In Performance Point Services we must create a connection to the data source or sources we want to use in dashboard. All data used in Performance Point Services is external data, living in data repositories outside of Performance Point. After we establish a data connection, we will be able to use the data in the various Performance Point feature areas.But apart for data fetching any other point which we can analysis the performance of data source??

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what do you mean by type of data source for high performance? Here i am **assuming** that you are asking **which type of data source should we use for a faster generation of dashboard/report?**

Below are my #2Cents to the question:- 
 
1. In my experience as data analyst (using SSIS to integrate the various data source into one platform for generation of desired data set); I've come across that usually, i am unable to pick what type of files i would like to receive (eg. some system only produce flat files, some CSV, others only excel, etc) but the **trick is this**: for **faster generation** of your desired dashboard:- 
   a. Be very clear on what is your final desired variables needed from each data source 

 
   b. Make sure that the source file are clean before loading it as dashboard data source (many a        times, when source file date is clean, the task for data manipulation and also extracting out        desired data becomes much easier with clean data 

2. Selecting the right tool to use for the integration of multiple data sources. (This is vital in terms of what are the current Database environment are your data stored, what is the format of your final file, etc)

Hope i've been able to help a little.

Best of Luck! :)